# Simple defense offense strategy

Tags: php, math, probability

I am have to make this basic game engine.The offensive player has 5/6 chance to make a shot(83%).. And defense player has 4/6 chance(57.6%) to defend it.So when offensive player make a shot,how do I calculate the success rate of both players.Thank you for taking time to read this.I am starting new in this.Thanks in advance..

Comment: You will get more helpful responses if you tell us what programming language you are planning to write in.

Comment: @Kaelin Thanks for replying.. it is php..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might picture the cases like this:

```
|                  | Defense succeeds | Defense fails |
| Offense succeeds | miss             | hit           |
| Offense fails    | miss             | miss          |
```

So the probability of a hit is

```
(Offense succeeds)*(1-Defense succeeds)
```

In your example above,

```
5/6 * (1 - (4/6)) = 0.278
```

---

Note: How you want to handle the case of `Offense succeeds` and `Defense succeeds` is up to you. You might want to consider that a hit, not a miss... But if you do, then the probability of a hit would just be `Offense succeeds`, and would not depend on `Defense succeeds` at all. That would seem odd since it implies the defense has no affect on the offense whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. So formula must be (.83)*(1-.57)??To get the success rate??

Comment: Yes, except that 4/6 = 0.66 NOT 0.57.

Comment: ok..got that cleared..Thanks again

Comment: Any idea how I would implement this in php.. Like the player kicks, The ball must get in the net 0.278(i.e) 27% sucess rate..

Comment: I don't know the details of PHP, but you'd want to generate a (uniformly distributed) random number from 0 to 1, and if the random number is less than 0.278, then treat the kick as a success.

Comment: yes,your right :)... that must be the way..Thanks again.. good day!